# Powershell: Run a .dll inside linux

Tags: c#, linux, cross-platform, .net-6.0, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I hava a powershell script, that works fine for windows.
At the end of the script, I run a .exe

```
& "mypathWin\My.exe"
```

As the .exe is developed with .NET6, I can run the .dll inside wsl without any problems.
When I usually run . dll inside wsl I use

```
dotnet myApp.dll
```

But when I try to run my powershell script inside wsl it doesn't work.
Inside my script I have changed all path to linux standard and adjusted the line that runs .exe to

```
& "mypathLinux\My.dll"
```

But this is not working. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `dotnet mypathLinux/My.dll` in wsl, as you would do by hand.

Alternatively, you can publish for linux during build (with `dotnet publish...`), after which you get a file that is just called "My", which is the equivalent of the ".exe" file for windows.

Comment: yes, I tried this as well a few minutes ago and got the error: comamnd not found. 
Maybe I start the .ps1 file wrong? I start it like this: ./MyScript.ps1

Comment: You need to make sure the `dotnet` binary is in the path. Make sure `which dotnet` and `dotnet --info` work.

Comment: dotnet is working correctly. dotnet --info gives me all the infos it should be giving me. But when I run ./MyScript.ps1, which contains only: dotnet MyPath.dll 
I get an error: d otnet: command not found (There realy is a space in d onet)

Comment: ./test.ps1: line 1: d otnet: command not found

Comment: Hmm... I'm not a powershell expert, but I think you can't have a powershell script just consisting of a single line. You need to have a function in there. Look for powershell tutorials.